# StaggeredGridView change long click colour

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-xml, android-adapter

I want to change the background colour of my StaggeredGridView item when pressed, but currently I am getting an ugly gingerbread orange by default, as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y79WN.jpg). I tried setting the gridview items background as a selector, but when I did that, if I click one item, all the items' background colours are changed.

```
<!-- My selector -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_light"
      android:state_pressed="true" />    
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And this was in my StaggeredGridView, but it didn't help:

```
 <!-- In StaggeredGridView -->
 android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
```

By the way, I am using [this](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) StaggeredGridView Library. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution was to stay away from any @color or @drawable that refers
>   to a color inside listSelector. I created two 3x3 pixel .png files.
>   Each saved with the gamma layer. In my case it's two of the same color
>   each mixed down in Gimp with a different transparency on the color
>   layer. So when you select an item you get an overlay with 25% color,
>   and when you press it you get a png with 50% color. I put them in my
>   drawables as bg_list_item_pressed.png and bg_list_item_highlighted.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_highlighted" /> <!--  @drawable/tab_focus -->

  <!-- Pressed -->
  <item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_pressed" /> <!--  @drawable/tab_press -->

</selector>
```

then

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

at the implementation of staggeredGridViews onClick event:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    for(int i=0;i<mGridView.getChildCount();i++) {
        mGridView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow)); 
       // set all items to yellow
    }
    mGridView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)); 
    //set the selected items color to blue
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hey, you should consider adding an explanation to your answer so OP really understands it.

Answer (score 1):

you should change a line in that library and than make your own selector

1) in the library there is a class called: `StaggeredGridView`

there is a method in that class called: `useDefaultSelector()`

inside that comment the setSelector line and add this line:

```
setSelector(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector));
```

2)make an xml file inside drawable folder in the library as follow: `selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />


<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/yourColor1" />
<item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/yourColor2" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@color/yourColor3" />

</selector>
```